# Advanced Filter on Excel using multiple AND / OR filters

Tags: excel, advanced-filter

I am having trouble filtering my document using multiple "and, or" clauses on columns in excel.

My document has 27,000 rows and 37 columns. In the first initial rows I have my advance filter set in place [I have attached a picture of how my advanced filter is set now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PakCP.png). The resulting product of the filter I have set up is not what I intended. In human readable form I was trying to ask "What numbers in the 0-30 column rise above 2, and of those numbers that rise above 2 in the 0-30 column which fall back under .5 in one or more of the subsequent columns."

I appreciate anyone who takes the time to help me translate my human readable format into machine code, if you need further information please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You just need to continue the `>=2` down column A while continuing to stagger the `<=0.5` filters one column at a time.

[image: advanced_filter_multiple_OR]
                        <sup>Setting up the criteria</sup>

The theory behind this is that values across columns in a single row are treated as `AND` criteria while values in subsequent rows are treated like `OR` criteria. You want a combination of both.

> <sup>WHERE (column A >= 2.0 AND column B <= 0.5)
>
>           OR (column A >= 2.0 AND column C <= 0.5)
>
>           OR (column A >= 2.0 AND column D <= 0.5)
>
>           OR (column A >= 2.0 AND column E <= 0.5)
>
>           (etc ...)</sup>

[image: advanced_filter_multiple_OR_results]
                        <sup>With Advanced Filter applied</sup>

Comment: Jeeped, this is very helpful!

Comment: Jeeped, could you help me write a script in VBA to automate this filter across the worksheet? i.e move the >=2 right one column and the <=.5 to replace the column the >=2 left.

Comment: That may be a new question. Typically, when the scope of a question changes sufficiently enough to render previously correct answers invalid, the original question should be closed and a new question should be posed. A new question also has the advantage of giving you space to start with a fresh narrative (and possibly modified  data) to illustrate the next issue.

Comment: Thank you for filling me in.

Comment: Couple of pointers: first off, TRY SOMETHING. Questions that include some attempt at code (working or not) receive prompt focused help and upvotes. Questions asking for code but not showing any attempt generally receive *'Where is your code?'* comments and down-votes. Also, a small portion (doesn't have to be 30 columns wide) of sample data together with expected results goes a long way to helping people understand what point you are trying to get across. Not everyone speaks perfect english but we all understand code and data.

Comment: Will do, as a geneticist coding is all new to me. I will use what you have said to formulate better questions in the future.